# Can I search for values to match results from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do is line up a value together from 2 dataframes but they differ in shape and size.

Say I want to extract column D from one of the dataframe and append it to another

DataFrame1:

```
A   B   C   D
1   1   0   2
1   4   0   1
1   0   2   4
2   2   3   0
2   1   0   1
```

Dataframe2

```
A   B   C   D
1   1   0   54
1   4   0   10
1   0   2   54
2   2   3   55
2   1   0   34
```

outcome I'm looking for:

```
A   B   C   D  newD
1   1   0   2  54
1   4   0   1  10
1   0   2   4  54
2   2   3   0  55
2   1   0   1  34
```

I tried this

```
DataFrame1['newD'] = DataFrame2.loc[DataFrame1[['A', 'B', 'C']] == DataFrame2['A', 'B', 'C']]['D']
```

but I got a keyword error: `KeyError: ('A', 'B', 'C')`

Is there an easy way to get this result?

bonus question - Is it possible to have multiple criteria in search(i.e. D not null or something?)?

Comment: `DataFrame2['A', 'B', 'C']` should be `DataFrame2[['A', 'B', 'C']]`. But that only fixes the listed error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it `merge`:

```
pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['A','B','C'], how='left')
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D_x  D_y
0  1  1  0    2   54
1  1  4  0    1   10
2  1  0  2    4   54
3  2  2  3    0   55
4  2  1  0    1   34
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked in my example. I just tried it on my specific usecase and I think because one of my columns is numeric and the other is a string, I'm getting this error : ValueError: You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: Like the error says, you have `Int` type on one dataframe and `object` type on the other. You need to double check with `df.dtypes`.

Comment: thank you. I didn't realize it was because my variables were not the same. works great. Right now it converts everything..if I only wanted one column is there a way to select the column I want to see(in this case D and not all the columsn?)